# tableview rows lines are not distributed

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I am doing a very simple tableview (just to test) (using xcode9.1 ,swift4)
when I simulate the lines between rows are not distributed right. some rows will have a line between them and some don't have a line between them. [here is a screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMcpv.jpg) 
thanks for any help...
here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

let list=["milk","honey","bread","tomatoes"]
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (list.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
    return (cell)
}

}
```

Comment: your sumilator screen in 3x you need to make it 1x full screen.

Comment: thats simulator problem. just scroll up down to see separator lines or run in actual physical device.

Comment: in simulator , due to resolution it will show lines like this only.. run it in real device all lines of selector will be seen

Comment: That will not happen in device only you can face this in simulator because that is not actual screen size

Comment: thanks @JD. and @– D.Desai and  Ganesh Manickam I believe I have to run it on real device. but does that mean I can not get real fell of how tableview will look like until I run it on a real device?